# Compare 2 datasets (one to many rows)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dataset

VB.NET Winforms

I need to compare 2 datatables (that are each within their own dataset) and conclude with a judgement of OK or NG, one is a reference table, the other is raw data from a machine. One table would have one row with a QTY, the other table would have multiple rows to match that QTY, hopefully. The purpose here is verify torque values on fasteners. The first table here is the data I would get as what would be required for the torques to pass. Let's call this table `dtTorquesRequired`:

```
NINDEX      NQTY_REQ    NMIN    NMAX
7           1           33.0    59.0
8           4           33.0    59.0
9           2           4.5     7.5
12          2           4.5     7.5
```

NINDEX will be the common column between the 2 datasets.

Let's use the last row as an example. The last row tells me that I need to have 2 torques from NINDEX 12 with a value between 4.5 - 7.5.

This is the data that I have to judge. Let's call this table `dtTorquesPerformed`:

```
NINDEX              NTORQUE_NO NTORQUE_STATUS NTORQUE_VALUE
7                    1          1              42.56
8                    1          1              42.22
8                    2          1              42.49
8                    3          1              42.10
8                    4          1              42.37
9                    1          1              7.01
9                    2          1              7.10
12                   1          1              5.68
12                   2          1              5.81
```

The judgement needs to have NINDEX match between the 2 tables, NTORQUE_STATUS must be 1, and NTORQUE_VALEU must be between NMIN and NMAX in dtTorquesRequired.

Now, I am currently doing this in my application using only SQL row count results, but it is slow. I am doing it via multiple chatty calls instead of a chunky call to the DB, and then work with the resulting datasets.

This is how I am currently doing it, but it is slow. I want to do all the processing locally instead of using SQL:

```
Private Function TorqueJudgement(ckanban As String) As Boolean
    Dim ccode As String
    Dim cline As String
    Dim dsTorquesRequired As New DataSet
    Dim dtTorquesRequired As New DataTable
    Dim AreAllTorquesGood As Boolean = False
    Dim BadTorqueCount As Int16 = 0

    ccode = ckanban.Substring(0, 5)
    cline = ckanban.Substring(5, 2)

        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT ....") ''GETS DTTORQUESREQUIRED

    dsTorquesRequired = SQL.SQLDS
    dtTorquesRequired = dsTorquesRequired.Tables(0)
    dtTorquesRequired.Columns.Add("PassFail")

    Dim rc As Int16 = -1 '// 
    For Each dr As DataRow In dsTorquesRequired.Tables(0).Rows
        rc += 1
        Dim nindex As Int16 = dr("NINDEX")
        Dim qtyrequired As Int16 = dr("NQTY_REQ")
        Dim nmin As Decimal = dr("NMIN")
        Dim nmax As Decimal = dr("NMAX")

        SQL.AddParam("@CKANBAN", ckanban)
        SQL.AddParam("@NINDEX", nindex)
        SQL.AddParam("@QTY_REQ", qtyrequired)
        SQL.AddParam("@NMIN", nmin)
        SQL.AddParam("@NMAX", nmax)
        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT ...") ''Searches for rows that match dtTorquesRequired

        dtTorquesRequired.Rows(rc)("PassFail") = SQL.RecordCount
        If Not dtTorquesRequired.Rows(rc)("NQTY_REQ") <= dtTorquesRequired.Rows(rc)("PassFail") Then
            BadTorqueCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    If BadTorqueCount > 0 Then
        AreAllTorquesGood = False
    ElseIf BadTorqueCount = 0 Then
        AreAllTorquesGood = True
    End If

    Return AreAllTorquesGood
End Function
```

How can I query a datatable object locally using VB.NET without using SQL

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should turn set `Option Strict On`.  That "SQL Helper" has to result in many of data type conversions as well.  DataTables can be queried, so unless there are many many rows, you could do that rather than run a new query for each row.

Comment: If you are using sql server 2008 and above, you can use [Table-Value Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#creating-table-valued-parameter-types), which you can use to pass an entire data table to a stored procedure and process it in bulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataView` objects to "query" `DataTables`:

```
Dim dtb As New DataTable
dtb.Columns.Add("Col0")
dtb.Columns.Add("Col1")
dtb.Columns.Add("Col2")
dtb.Columns.Add("Col3")
dtb.Rows.Add("R0C0", "R0C1", "A", "A")
dtb.Rows.Add("R1C0", "R1C1", "A", "A")
dtb.Rows.Add("R2C0", "R2C1", "A", "B")
dtb.Rows.Add("R3C0", "R3C1", "B", "B")

Dim dvw As New DataView(dtb)
dvw.RowFilter = "Col0>'R1C0'" 'WHERE 
dvw.Sort = "Col2 DESC" 'ORDER BY
For Each drv As DataRowView In dvw
  Dim drw As DataRow = drv.Row
  Console.WriteLine(drw("Col0") & " " & drw("Col1") & " " & drw("Col2") & " " & drw("Col3"))
Next
Dim dtbDistinct As DataTable = dtb.DefaultView.ToTable(True, {"Col2", "Col3"}) 'DISTINCT
For Each drw As DataRow In dtbDistinct.Rows
  Console.WriteLine(drw("Col2") & " " & drw("Col3"))
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: This is interesting.  Thank you. I was unaware of the DataView constructor and what it could do.